# How to do sparse checkout in git using Java

Tags: java, git, egit, jgit

I want to perform sparse checkout in GIT i.e. checking out a portion of working copy from repository.How can I do this by a Java code.Pls suggest.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407461/how-do-i-implement-sparse-checkout-in-jgit

Answer (score 2):

Based on [@rüdiger-herrmann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29508999/125617):

```
String url = "https://github.com/renaud/solr_noLenghNormSimilarity";
String hash = "802558f58add3a1f5b33f04254194bd7cd59b27f";
String subPath = "src/org";
String dest = "myclone";

File localPath = new File(dest);

Git gitRepo = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(url).setDirectory(localPath).setNoCheckout(true).call();
gitRepo.checkout().setStartPoint(hash).addPath(subPath).call();
gitRepo.getRepository().close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently the JGit library (as of 3.0.0) doesn't support sparse checkouts.