# Is partial checkout supported by JGit 3.7?

Tags: jgit

I am using Jgit 3.7 for importing files from Git repository. But I would like to import only set of folders instead of all. 
I know Git supports this, but I would like to know Jgit 3.7 supports the same? If so, can someone guide me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the native Git command that you would like to emulate?

Comment: @Rudiger. Thanks for for your quick reply. I have tried below command for getting files from git repository. 'Git.cloneRepository().setURI(uri).setDirectory(new File(dir)).call()'. This command download all the source files. But I am not sure, how to import particular directory and its subdirectories and files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By design, a cloned git repository always contains all files and folders of the original repository.

With native git, you can create a [shallow clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) (`git clone --depth 1 ...`) <strike>but this feature is [not yet implemented in JGit](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=301627)</strike>.
EDIT 2023-06-13:
As of [version 6.3](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.jgit/releases/6.3.0) JGit
supports shallow fetch and clone.

Contradicting its general design, native git (since version 1.7) lets you create partial clones with [sparse checkouts](http://briancoyner.github.io/blog/2013/06/05/git-sparse-checkout/) but this is also not possible out-of-the-box in JGit.

What you can do in JGit though - once you have cloned a repository - is to [checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) only some files of a branch or commit.

```java
git.checkout().setStartPoint("some-branch").addPath("path/to/file").call()
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Jgit is yet to implement the solution for sparse checkouts. Better what I can do is, Clone the whole repository and delete the unwanted directory and its files.

Comment: adding specific path to the checkout the commit history is dissociated , so you can't  push it back to the original branch and if u create a new named branch . The new branch containing only the few specified files can't be merged  back to the main branch as they have different commit history

Comment: This is very nice; I used it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76383350 along with the new JGit support in v6.5.0 for `setDepth(1)`. Note though that when `setDepth(1)` along with `setNoCheckout(true)`, this technique does not seem to work with `setStartPoint("main")` (where `main` is the branch). I suppose because there is no checkout, there is no branch. However `setStartPoint(hash)` and `setStartPoint("HEAD")` work.

Answer (score -1):

Based on @rüdiger-herrmann's answer:

```
String url = "https://github.com/renaud/solr_noLenghNormSimilarity";
String hash = "802558f58add3a1f5b33f04254194bd7cd59b27f";
String subPath = "src/org";
String dest = "myclone";

File localPath = new File(dest);

Git gitRepo = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(url).setDirectory(localPath).setNoCheckout(true).call();
gitRepo.checkout().setStartPoint(hash).addPath(subPath).call();
gitRepo.getRepository().close();
```