# How to checkout a certain folder with JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

```java
FetchResult fr = git.fetch().setCredentialsProvider(credentials).setCheckFetchedObjects(true).Call();
git.checkout().setCreateBranch(true).setName("origin/" + branchName).setStartPoint("origin/" + branchName + "path/to/folder").call()
```

This is the code I'm using to check out a single folder from a remote repository.
Equivalent git commands are:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/branch -- path/to/folder
```

But, the Java code doesn't work for me, I was only able to initialise the local repository and configure remote repository. The checkout didn't work and I couldn't find out what mistake I'm making.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is partial checkout supported by JGit 3.7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505919/is-partial-checkout-supported-by-jgit-3-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making changes in the checkout part like this

`"origin/"`

and give it a try.

Otherwise you want to do is a `sparse checkout`

[How do I implement sparse checkout in JGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407461/how-do-i-implement-sparse-checkout-in-jgit)

Comment: I tried it, no use. And as well , I only want to checkout a particular folder from a unique branch,  and checking out straight away from origin/ would give me the entire merged code, wouldn't it? And I don't want that.

Comment: I think what you want to do is a `sparse checkout`. Pls check this link
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

Answer (score 1):

In order to check out a particular folder with JGit (a sparse checkout), you need to tell the `CheckoutCommand` which folder to check out.

For example:

```java
git.checkout().setName("branch-to-check-out").addPath("path/to/folder").call();
```

`addPath()` can be called multiple times to check out each of the given paths. The path is interpreted relative to the work directory.